# How do I code <tab> to get over/out of parenthesis/quote in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

how do I code .vimrc using  key to get out of parenthesis in vim

ex) in insert mode

```
before:

if (Sample Code|) {}
"              ^cursor
```

and using tab

```
after:

if (Sample Code)| {}
"               ^here's the cursor
```

Comment: This question will likely soon get downvoted if you don't edit it to add more details. Add some example text showing the situation (i.e. a string with some parentheses/quotes and indicate where you cursor is positioned, then add a second example of what you want after you press tab).

Comment: Or you could simply press `<Right>` and keep `<Tab>` as-is.

Comment: @Sangin Lee - Do you require a certain behavior for TAB when not inside parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just hit <kbd>Escape</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> by force
of habit. A single key alternative is the right arrow key. If you really want
tab to do the job of the right arrow key, you could use the following mapping:

```
inoremap <TAB> <C-o><RIGHT>
```

It use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> from insert mode to execute a single
normal mode command before returning to insert mode (see `:help i_ctrl-o`)